# Can I get duration of the videos from YouTuve API3.0 even if it's search result?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, youtube, youtube-api

I know it can get duration if fetch particular video directly.
What if it's search result?

I'm pretty sure that it provides us video's title, unique ID, and published date.

In my code below, any error won't occur unless I put **contentDetails** into 4th line.

It seems that the error occurs when there are more than two in part section.
If I leave it just as **:part => 'snippet',**, everything works fine.
However I have to add contentDetails to gain information about duration of the videos on Youtube.

How can I achieve it?

**videos_controller.rb**

```
@search_response = client.execute!(
  :api_method => youtube.search.list,
  :parameters => {
    :part => 'snippet, contentDetails',
    :q => 'cats',
    :maxResults => 20,
    :order => 'date',
    :pageToken => pageToken
  }
)
```

**Error**

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `prev_page_token' for nil:NilClass):
    1: 
    2: <% if !@search_response.prev_page_token.nil? %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the part parameter of the Search:list request doesn't take `contentDetails`. The documentation for the part parameter in the Search:list request explains it like this :

> The part parameter specifies a comma-separated list of one or more
>   search resource properties that the API response will include. Set the
>   parameter value to snippet.

Notice that it says :

> one or more **search resource** properties

But the search resource doesn't contain the `contentDetails` property. So I think you might be getting a `badRequest (400)` response.

But you do get the video's duration in `contentDetails` property of a video resource.

---

**UPDATE**

Okay if you have decided to use [Videos: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list)  API, so that you can get the `contentDetails` of all the videos in the search result with a single request, this is one way to do it (I'm assuming that the request gets a successful response) :

```
# Get the search result like you did.
@search_response = client.execute!(
  :api_method => youtube.search.list,
  :parameters => {
    :part => 'id',
    :q => 'cats',
    :maxResults => 20,
    :order => 'date',
    :pageToken => pageToken
  }
)

# Extract the ids of only the videos in the search result and make
# a comma separated list. Note if there aren't any videos in the search
# result the ids will contain an empty string.
ids = @search_response.items.select do |item|
  # You only want the 'videos'.
  item.id.kind == 'youtube#video'
end.map do |video|
  # Gets the video's id.
  video.id.videoId
end.join(',')

# Now use it to get the list of videos with content details from 
# Videos: list.
@videos = client.execute!(
  :api_method => youtube.video.list,
  :parameters => {
    # Whatever you want from a Video resource.
    :part => 'snippet, contentDetails',
    :id => ids
  }
)
```

Note these videos correspond to the ones you get in a single search (one you do above), and I'm not really sure if the order of the result is the same as the search result. I think you can now use `@videos` to get the details of the videos instead of using `@search_response`, but you will have to depend on `@search_response` to control the search parameters like queries and pagination.

Comment: Thanks so much. So I have to request contentDetails for every each video? It's so pain that they didn't consider for this kind of demand:(

Comment: No problem :). From what I know, it's right that you will have to do that for every video. But I know very little of the API, there might be another way to do this. I will give it a read. Or maybe I think you can undo the answer accept and wait for another answers that gives a way to fetch that too.

Comment: @limrkin thanks! okay then let's wait for another answer for 1 more day and after that I'll make your answer as correct one again. Thanks anyway:)

Comment: Alright. Btw, there is this API : Video:list, that can give you a list of videos given a list of ids, it can contain `contentDetails`, but it costs quota.It doesn't support search queries obviously, but can help you in retrieving the `contentDetails` of all the fetched videos within 1 request.

Comment: Thanks for providing another idea. As you said, I have to use search query in my situation so that I cannot adopt that idea. Thanks, though!

Comment: Oh no, I mean you have to search the videos with the Search:list, and use Videos:list to get the contentDetails of all the fetched videos by using a single request, rather than issuing a request for each of the videos fetched with Search:list.